# NGINX URL rewrite for static files in different directories

Tags: regex, nginx

Could some dome please help me resolve this issue .
I would like to write ALL occurrences of

```
name.css.v=abc1234.css
```

to

```
name.css
```

and

```
name.js.v=abc123.js
```

to

```
name.js
```

I have tried using

```
rewrite /([a-z,\d]+.css)(.v=[a-z,\d]+.css$)/i $1  last;
```

but it doesn't work

BTW , 
there are files in different directories such as

```
/a/b/c/something.css.v=sssaa1223.css 
/d/e/f/anotherfile.css.v=12333asss.css
/g/h/i/somejsfile.js.v=123sdsd.js
/j/k/l/alienfile.js.v=askdlsk12asd.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the nginx syntax, but this regex should work fine for your problem:

`rewrite /(\w+.(css|js))(.v=.*)/i $1 last;`

http://regexr.com?340lv

Comment: The following works for me now :) location ~* \.(css|js)  { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rules; 
} 

location @rules { 
    rewrite  ^([a-zA-Z\d\S]+\.css)([\SA-Za-z,\d]+\.css)$ $1 last ;
}